# How to setup a localhost (behind VPN) proxy for Android device connected

Tags: android, http, proxy, localhost, vpn

I was searching a lot, however, I'm wondering if it's possible to create such a configuration:

I have my desktop HP notebook at home that's connected to a regular Huawei router that's LTE enabled. In this notebook, I have a VPN setup to be able to view specific pages (Corpo-internal like). One page has a bug, but I can reproduce it using the android device only.

I don't have (and I will not have) a VPN on this android device (tablet).

I can see two possibilities:

1) connect the Android device to the notebook and force tablet to use HP's ethernet (let's say somehow emulate HP's browser on the tablet)?

2) setup a proxy(?) on HP for HTTP requests coming from a tablet?

Many thanks for you hints.